# Convert Aug 19th 2018 into 08-19/2018-Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to convert a string of date "Aug 19th 2018" into "mm-dd-yyyy" format( without using the moment.js)
 I used

```
d = new Date("Aug 19th 2018")
```

it results into NaN as its unable to parse "19th". How to achieve this?

Comment: the date string that is passed is not a valid format. the mdn link might be of some help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date. Here is an excerpt that states about dateString format 
> The string should be in a format recognized by the Date.parse() method (IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps and also a version of ISO8601).

Comment: yours is not a valid input to Date.you can try d = new Date("2018-08-19");
and alert((d.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate() + '-' +  date.getFullYear());

Comment: I think @AravindS got it right, you could just `new Date("Aug 19th 2018".replace("th",""))` to get it to parse right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom function and convert  a date to required format

```js
let dt = "Aug 19th 2018";


function convertDate(dt) {
  let newFormat = "";
  // a mapping of month name and numerical value
  let monthMapping = {
    jan:'01',
    feb: '02',
    mar: '03',
    april: '04',
    may: '05',
    june: '06',
    july: '07',
    aug: '08',
    sept: '09',
    oct: '10',
    nov: '11',
    dec: '12'
  }
  // split the input string into three pieces
  let splitDt = dt.split(" ");
  // from the first piece get the numerical month value from the above obhect
  let getMonth = monthMapping[splitDt[0].toLowerCase()];
  let date = parseInt(splitDt[1], 10)
  let year = splitDt[2]
  return `${getMonth}-${date}-${year}`
}

console.log(convertDate(dt))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `split()` the string, Use the object to get the month index and use `parseInt()` to extract the number from the day.

Use `new Date(year, monthIndex , day)` to get the date object.

```
let formatDate = s => {
  let months = {jan:'0',feb:'1',mar:'2',apr:'3', may:'4',jun:'5',jul:'6',aug:'7',sep:'8',oct:'9',nov:'10',dec:'11'};
  let [m, d, y] = s.split(' ');
  return new Date(y, months[m.toLowerCase()], parseInt(d));
};

var date1 = formatDate("Aug 19th 2018");
var date2 = formatDate("Mar 19th 2000");
```

Doc: [new Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Answer (score 2):

You can replace all the letters in date value with regex and then pass the string again into the Date() constructor

```js
var dateString = "AUG 19th 2018";
var dateFrag = dateString.split(' ');
dateFrag[1] = dateFrag[1].replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g,'');
var d = new Date(dateFrag);
console.log(d);
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** you can first replace that 'th', 'rd'

```js
var mydate= new Date(ReturnProperDate("Aug 19th 2018"));

//you can create manual function to handle format now
console.log( (1+mydate.getMonth()) +"-"+ mydate.getDate()+"-" + mydate.getFullYear());

function ReturnProperDate(date){

  date=date.replace('th','');
  date=date.replace('rd','');
  date=date.replace('xx',''); //if any other
  
  return date;
  

}
```

use moment js  : https://momentjs.com/

then you can get easily your date in your desire formate

```
 moment(yourDate).format('DD-MMM-YYYY'); // put format as you want 

 moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // June 28th 2018, 9:58:10 am
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, unfortunately I cant use moment or any library in this case. how can execute this with a js function?

Comment: This also fails on `th` so no big loss there. You need to `moment(yourDate, formatYouAreUsing).format(formatYouWant)`. -- if moment was an option.

Comment: moment('Aug 19th 2018').toString()
"Invalid date"

Answer (score 1):

@Saurin Vala's solution has a problem, as moment js doc says , when parsing string, a format must be given or it will under the hood will construct js Date() which may not work on some browsers [take a look at the issue on moment js doc](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/).
proper way would be like this

```
var a = moment("Aug 19th 2018", 'MMM Do YYYY')
```

[date formating link](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

now you can out put the format in many ways

Answer (score 1):

Try String.replace():

```js
var str='Aug 19th 2018'.replace(/(\w{3})\s(\d{1,})\w{2}\s(\d{4})/,function(match,m,d,y){
  return ({'Jan':'01','Feb':'02','Mar':'03','Apr':'04','May':'05','Jun':'06','Jul':'07','Aug':'08','Sep':'09','Oct':'10','Nov':'11','Dec':'12'})[m]+'-'+d+'/'+y;
});
console.log(str);
```